# Android firebase robo testlab gcloud client not taking in login arguments

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I am trying to setup an robo test with gcloud test lab following this: 
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/firebase/test/android/run

Even though the firebase trigger happens and sometimes the username/password fields are typed in (as seen in the video) all of them don't happen at the same time and hence the robo keeps running only in the login UI.

`gcloud firebase test android run \
--type robo \
--app app/build/outputs/apk/*debug.apk \
--device model=NexusLowRes,version=26 \
--timeout 5m \
--robo-directives text:authui_sign_in_username_edit_text=username \
--robo-directives text:authui_sign_in_password_edit_text=password \
--robo-directives click:authui_sign_in_button=`

Anything that I am doing wrong here?

Incidentally I also got the same problem from the testlab GUI
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.  First, there is a non-beta version of the documentation available.  [Refer to this instead](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run).

Also, note in the documentation there that --robo-directives takes:

> A **comma-separated** (< type >:< key >=< value >) map of robo_directives that
>   you can use to customize the behavior of Robo test.

It shows an example:

> ```
> --robo-directives text:username_resource=username,text:password_resource=password
> ```

In other words, don't use multiple flags, bundle them all into the same flag in a comma-separated list.

Comment: Got the same help/suggestion from yinfu from firebase-community.slack.com. Thanks!

Comment: We had an issue with that only when we selected a `Virtual` device for testing. It works with `Physical` devices...